# How to count the number of characters before a certain word appearing several times in a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've found the below formula to count the number of characters preceeding a certain word, following the solution provided here:

[Count number of characters before a certain word in cell](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/479413-count-number-characters-before-certain-word-cell-post2368326.html#post2368326)

```
=SEARCH("apple",A2)-1
```

My issue is the following:

How to count the intermediary characters between 2 occurrences of the same word in a single cell?

Adapting Nicole's example found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/479413-count-number-characters-before-certain-word-cell-post2368303.html#post2368303)):

*"I need to count the number of characters in a text string before a word. For example, lets say the word is "Apple". and the text string is "I plucked an apple from that beautiful tree". In this case the number of characters is 13."*

Let say my example is:

"I plucked an `apple`, from the red `apple` tree".

The `=SEARCH("apple",A2)-1` formula returns the number of characters up to the 1st occurence of the word "`apple`". Which would be 13.

How to count the number of characters inbetween the 2 occurences of the word "`apple`" with a script?

Which would be the length of "`, from the red`"?

Or is it possible to do it by adapting the formula `=SEARCH("apple",A2)-1`?

Thanks so much for your help and guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX(LEN(SPLIT($A$1,"apple",0)))
```

- `SPLIT` the text by `apple`
- Calculate `LEN`gth of each string
- `INDEX` to get the respective index in the array

  ```
  =INDEX(LEN(SPLIT($A$1,"apple",0)),2)
  ```

```js
var str = "I plucked an apple, from the red apple tree";
var len = str.split('apple', 2).map(e=>e.length);
console.info(len);
console.info(len[1]);
```

Comment: Hi @TheMaster! Good to hear back from you! I'll do the test and respond asap! Talk soon.

Comment: Great code @TheMaster! it works well and easily for more than 2 occurrences also, by simply updating the index number! Here the demo for 3 occurrences of "apple": [Sheet3](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v6jTVZQY-5aneKUhwpMqurnVZelUsnQFNQueFFH0yA4/edit#gid=1554215109) Thanks a lot! Great way to solve it!

Comment: @Lod Notice that the first formula is written without specifying a index row number to return all the results.

Comment: Hi @TheMaster! Thanks for the notice about the row. I've tested the INDEX with 0 as row index (as explained in the [INDEX documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en) it would return all the values). And it indeed returns all the results in separate cells on the right. Using this code `=INDEX(LEN(SPLIT($A27,"apple",0)),0)` in [Sheet3 cell B27](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v6jTVZQY-5aneKUhwpMqurnVZelUsnQFNQueFFH0yA4/edit?usp=sharing). That's working as needed for all strings/sentences that end on the same cell.

Comment: I've tried to use the following IFS/RIGHT statement `=IFS(RIGHT(A34,1)=".",INDEX(LEN(SPLIT($A34,"apple",0)),0))` to see make it return the indexes values upon the condition `RIGHT(A34,1)="."` , but now it only returns the 1st index in B34 [Sheet3 B34](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v6jTVZQY-5aneKUhwpMqurnVZelUsnQFNQueFFH0yA4/edit?usp=sharing). Why doesn't it return the other indexes as when upon no condition? What alternative do you see to make it return all the indexes as before?

Comment: @Lod enclose the whole formula in `ARRAYFORMULA()` and use `IF` instead.

Comment: Great @TheMaster, it's working! `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(RIGHT(A34,1)=".",INDEX(LEN(SPLIT($A34,"apple",0)),0)))` I will look again why it works with the `ARRAYFORMULA()` and try it with the second one. Thanks a lot talk soon.

Comment: @Lod Consider accepting the answer that helped you.

Comment: thanks for the reminder! I had forgotten to accept that one. I'll check my other older question asap just in case I forgot other ones. Be well!

Answer (score 3):

The search function can take a third parameter which is where in the string you want to start the search, so if you find the first instance of "apple" and then run another search starting at that position plus 1, you will find the second instance.

first instance:

```
=search("apple", A2)
```

second instance:

```
=search("apple", A2, search("apple", A2) + 1)
```

subtract the second from the first:

```
=search("apple", A2, search("apple", A2) + 1) - search("apple", A2)
```

To just get the length between you would have to subtract the length of the word "apple" or whatever you are searching for.

Comment: Hi @Aidan! Thanks a lot for that answer. I've finally understood the embedded way to use the 2nd search, starting in the 2nd agument from 1 position to the right of the 1st search. Then substracting the position of the 1st search. Finally substracting the number of characters from the 2nd character of the 1st search to the last character of the 1st search, and also substracting the 1st character of the 2nd search. Here's my tests on Sheet2: [Sheet2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v6jTVZQY-5aneKUhwpMqurnVZelUsnQFNQueFFH0yA4/edit?usp=sharing) Be well!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it with a script, you can play with the “indexOf” functions. It counts how many characters are from the beginning of the string until the word you introduce. 
indexOf works like this:

```
indexOf(string, [pos])
```

If you don’t specify any position it will start from the beginning, otherwise it will count from the position you introduced. 
With that being said, you can  apply the following logic:

```
var string = sheet.getRange("your cell").getValues().toString();

var apple_length = "apple".length;  
var first_apple = string.indexOf("apple") + apple_length;
var second_apple = string.indexOf("apple", first_apple);

var result = second_apple - first_apple;
```

Since it counts until it finds the word, we need to add the word’s length to the formula, and use that result as the starting position for the second indexOf.

For more information, check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

**EDIT**

```
var appletree = [];
var apple_length = "apple".length;
var char_counter = 0;

while (true) {

var apple = your_string.indexOf("apple", char_counter) + apple_length;

appletree.push(apple);

char_counter = char_counter + apple;


if (char_counter >= your_string.length) 
 break;

};
};
```

This is actually simpler and better as it doesn't matter the string length or how many apples you put.

Comment: Hi @Jescanellas! Thanks for that solution too! I will test it and come back with my results. Talk soon!

Comment: Hi again @Jescanellas!  I've adapted a working version of your script here: [JescanellasScript](https://pastebin.com/E32aq0SL). Thanks again, it's working for 2 occurrences of "apple".

Comment: Here the sheet [Sheet4](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v6jTVZQY-5aneKUhwpMqurnVZelUsnQFNQueFFH0yA4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I've consulted the documentation you shared and tried to extend the code to fit for 3 occurrences of "apple". But since "apple" occurrences are indiscriminate strings in the array, taking example from the source [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Finding_all_the_occurrences_of_an_element), I cannot see how to make it work for more than 2 occurences.

Comment: Here 2 tests I tried but it's not working: [1st test](https://pastebin.com/7FkRjhJj)  ,[2nd test](https://pastebin.com/zpGyfGPq) . Do you have some more ideas on how to make it work for more than 2 occurrences? Thanks a lot again! Take care!

Comment: I'm editing my answer as the code in comments is terrible

Comment: Hi @Jescanellas! I've clarified and extended my question into a new one here: [How to count the number of characters between each occurrences of a word occurring several times in a cell in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56683463/how-to-count-the-number-of-characters-between-each-occurrences-of-a-word-occurri) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
=FINDB("♥", SUBSTITUTE(A1, "apple", "♥"))-1
```

[image: 0]