# How to count the number of characters between each occurrences of a word occurring several times in a cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm extending and clarifying my previous question asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663445/how-to-count-the-number-of-characters-before-a-certain-word-appearing-several-ti/56664841?noredirect=1#comment99915842_56664841):

**How to return the number of characters between each 2 occurrences of a word in a cell?**

**And across 2 or more cells in a range/ 1 column of cells?**

For example:

[image]

Please see Sheet6 [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v6jTVZQY-5aneKUhwpMqurnVZelUsnQFNQueFFH0yA4/edit?usp=sharing)

Cell A2 contains 4 times the word "apple", each time separated by x number of characters.

**How to return those intermediary numbers as shown in [Sheet6](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v6jTVZQY-5aneKUhwpMqurnVZelUsnQFNQueFFH0yA4/edit?usp=sharing) columns B, C, D, and E?**

**How to do that with a script? Ideally for  the range of A2:A to set the relative characters counts per corresponding cells in ranges B2:B, C2:C, D2:D, E2:E, and F2:F?**

### Taking this string as example:

In A2:

```
0 apple one apple 2 apple three apple four.
```

The returned needed results would be set as:

In B2: 2
(for 2 the characters of the string "0(-)")

In C2: 5 
(for 5 the characters of the string "(-)one(-)")

In D2: 3 
(for 3 the characters of the string "(-)2(-)")

In E2: 7 
(for 7 the characters of the string "(-)three(-)")

In F2: 6 
(for 6 the characters of the string "(-)four.",
with the "." appearing as last character in 
the cell as taken criterion to close the count.)

### And this other example:

to take into account a string across 2 cells A3 and A4:

A3= `zero apple one apple 2`

A4= `apple three apple four.`

In B3: 5 
(for the 5 characters of the string "zero(-)")

In C3: 5 
(for the 5 characters of the string "(-)one(-)")

In D4: 3 
(for 3 the characters of the string "(-)2(-)".
In D4 because the next "apple" is one row below,
the count is set relatively one row below as well).

In E4: 7 
(for 7 the characters of the string "(-)three(-)")

In F4: 6 
(for 6 the characters of the string "(-)four.", 
with the "." appearing as last character in 
the cell taken as criterion to close the count.)

So far I've adapted [@Jescanellas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56664841/10789707) previous script to the following [here](https://pastebin.com/Kvx53VyB)

```
function numcharsbetweenocc1and2ofApple() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");

var your_string = sheet.getRange("B2").getValues().toString();


var appletree = [];
var apple_length = "apple".length;
var char_counter = 0;


while ("B2" !== "") {

var apple = your_string.indexOf("apple", char_counter) + apple_length;

appletree.push(apple);

char_counter = char_counter + apple;


var result = apple;

sheet.getRange("D2").setValue(result);




if (char_counter >= your_string.length)
 break;

};
};
```

But that returns the number of character up to the last occurrence of "apple". And only for one current cell, it doesn't work for the whole column when I change the `.getRange("B2")` to `.getRange("B2:B")` and `sheet.getRange("D2:D").setValue(result);` to `sheet.getRange("D2:D").setValue(result);`.
[Sheet4](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v6jTVZQY-5aneKUhwpMqurnVZelUsnQFNQueFFH0yA4/edit?usp=sharing)

Here again the expected result:

[image]

Sheet6 [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v6jTVZQY-5aneKUhwpMqurnVZelUsnQFNQueFFH0yA4/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks for your input and help!

Comment: @TheMaster I've answered to your other comment just now. Yes it works great for single cell string/sentence. When I add a conditional statement to it,  it returns only the 1st index index.

Comment: For the 2nd issue of multiple cells strings, I've done the following test: `=IFS(A39="","",RIGHT(A39,1)=".",INDEX(LEN(SPLIT(A39:A40,"apple",0)),0),AND(RIGHT(A39,1)<>".",RIGHT(A40,1)="."),INDEX(LEN(SPLIT(A39:A40,"apple",0)),0))` in [Sheet3 here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1v6jTVZQY-5aneKUhwpMqurnVZelUsnQFNQueFFH0yA4/edit?usp=sharing) . I've basically tried to make the index take input from a range `A39:A40` when `RIGHT(A39,1)<>".",RIGHT(A40,1)="."` is true, but here also it only returns the 1st index (5).

Comment: Basically, when it meets any cell in column A that doesn't has a period "." as last character, I would like to make it continue returning the indexes values until it meets a cell with a "." period as last character. And ideally have each index returned on the same row of it's corresponding location from it's direct input cell ( for example in screenshot above `(A3, 5 (B2), 5 (C2), on row 3`, then `A4, 3 (D4), 7 (E4), 6 (F4) on row 4`) .  Or if that's more convenient returning all those indexes on the adjacent cells to the right of the cell with the period "." as last character.

Comment: Again great code @TheMaster! Here the working formula following your `ARRAYFORMULA()` and `IF` observation instead of using `IFS` for the string/sentence across multiple cells: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A39="","",IF(RIGHT(A39,1)=".",INDEX(LEN(SPLIT(A39:A40,"apple",0)),0), IF(AND(RIGHT(A39,1)<>".",RIGHT(A40,1)="."),INDEX(LEN(SPLIT(A39:A40,"apple",0)),0)))))`. It returns all the indexes. I will try now to understand why it works with the `ARRAYFORMULA()` and `IF` and also possibly try to make it display the indexes as needed with offsets to the correct columns. Thanks a lot again! I'll come back asap.

Comment: You can add it as answer below, if that satisfies your question.

Comment: @TheMaster thanks, and I might do the same thing here.

Comment: Hi @TheMaster! I got a new idea. Using the `SPLIT` function on an adjacent column to the input column. Then on new adjacent columns retrieving and returning the numbers of the splits results. And finally hiding the intermediary/recursive operations columns. But the `SPLIT` function doesn't seem to allow delimiters with multiple characters. I've asked a new question about this issue [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/131108/how-to-use-the-split-function-in-google-spreadsheets-with-different-delimiters-a). Do you know if it is possible with the `SPLIT` function? Thanks a lot!